# using STD::List in c++

Tags: c++

well I am making a Sudoku puzzle, and I am trying to compare whether a number can go in a row because of the number already existing in a row, and im very new to c++ and well im okay at c# and I have this

```
for (int i= 0; i< fifth.size(); i++)
        {
            for (int c= 0; c<9; c++)
            {
                listConnectordown1[c] == fifth[i];


 //then the number can not go in here because it already exists in the row but not the
block
            }
        }
```

as you can see im getting the error at `listConnectordown1[c] == fifth[i];` because of lack of knowledge with c++ could anybody help me so I can compare them correctly?

the error is

```
4   IntelliSense: no operator "[]" matches these operands
        operand types are: std::list<int, std::allocator<int>> [ int ]  j:\08227 acw\ACW\Sudoku\Sudoku\main.cpp 152
```

**I have now changed to a vector given advice, now I don't know how to remove a certain value when it needs to be removed for example**

```
int possbileChecks[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
            std::vector<int> fifth (possbileChecks, possbileChecks + sizeof(possbileChecks) / sizeof(int) );
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            PossibleChecks = Block1[i][j];

            if (!PossibleChecks == 0)
            {
            PossibleValuesInsideBlock[count] = PossibleChecks;
            //ValueRemove = count-1;
            possiblValuesCount = PossibleChecks-1;
            fifth.Remove(PossibleChecks);
            possiblValuesCount=0;

            count = count++;
            }   

        }
        }
```

Comment: As a side note to ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀ's answer, `std::list` uses a linked list as the data structure. For a linked list, random access has `Big Oh(n)` complexity, where for an array, it is `Big Oh(1)`.

Comment: Exactly, it needs to traverse the entire list from beginning, or end (since it's doubly linked).

Comment: Note that your `sizeof` usage isn't needed in C++

Comment: I can't really read your current code. What is `PossibleChecks` and `Block1`?. I'd suggest that you have a 2d vector grid, and keep possible values in either a 3d vector (including the grid), or a map (coordinates to vector), or if you want to create them as you go, a simple vector will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

`std::list` doesn't provide index access functionality. It is implemented as a doubly linked list, so if you want to randomly access elements in the list it's probably not the right choice for you. What you probably want is `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<int> v(1);
v[0] = 0;

if(v[0] == 0)...
    ... // etc
```

If you want to stick to the list you should use iterator functions, like `begin` and `advance`.

Comment: Do you know how I remove a certain element out of a vector when I run through the loop, because it is no so simple as a list.

Comment: Don't you want your sudoku representation to have a fixed size (9x9)? You could simply set the value to `-1` to denote _"not set"_. Otherwise, you'll have relative positions, and removing an element offsets all other elements

Comment: I have edited my original post, I need to check what's inside a block then remove them values that already are inside but because now im using a vector its difficult.

Comment: @user3376687 You should probably rethink your design. Looping over the 9 possible values is a good start. And storing all possible values in a new vector is an option. Also, note that in C++0x you can simply do `fifth({0,1,2,3})` etc. (Initializer list).

Answer (score 0):

std::List in c++ is not the same as a list in C#, you aren't able to loop through list like this.

to iterate through std::list you will have to use an iterator(std::list::Iterator):

```
    list<int>::const_iterator it;
    for(it = list1.begin();it != list1.end();it++)
    {
        for(list<int>::const_iterator c = list1.begin();c != list1.end();c++)
        {
            c == it;
        }
    }
```

or use a range based for loop:

```
    //Range based for loop
    for(int i :list1)
    {
        for(int c : list2)
        {
            i == c;
        }
    }
```

or just use a std::vector instead of std::list and your code will work